# Adding x-axis lables on a faceted plot-ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, facet

I have a facetted `geom_col()` plot with [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) and I would like to have the x-axis labels on each level of the plots. So after each row, I would have the labels. My graph currently looks like this: [image]

```
dput(res2)
structure(list(X = structure(c(8L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 5L
), .Label = c("Blue", "Green", "Magenta", "Maroon", "Orange", 
"Pink", "Purple", "Red", "Yellow"), class = "factor"), Phenotype = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Blue", "Green", "Magenta", 
"Maroon", "Orange", "Pink", "Purple", "Red", "Yellow"), class = "factor"), 
    heritability = c(0.12, 0.14, 0.34, 0.21, 0.33, 0.35, 0.25, 
    0.49, 0.19, 0.42, -0.12, 0.4, 0.13, 0.42, 0.47, 0.2, 0.17, 
    0.14, -0.1, 0.14, 0.45, 0.24, 0.47, -0.28, 0.34, 0.18, 0.15, 
    0.37, -0.47, 0.12, 0.17, -0.11, 0.53, 0.41, -0.2, 0.14, 0.26, 
    0.45, 0.41, 0.48, 0.15, -0.35, 0.22, 0.32, 0.29, 0.47, 0.17, 
    -0.25, 0.27, 0.38, 0.52, -0.11, 0.5, 0.28, 0.34, 0.31, 0.52, 
    0.14, -0.23, 0.21, 0.11, -0.42, 0.39, 0.32, 0.51, 0.39, 0.15, 
    0.46, 0.5, 0.42, 0.46, 0.18), pvalue = c(0.05, 0.09, 0.05, 
    0.05, 0.09, 0.02, 0.01, 0.1, 0.05, 0.04, 0.08, 0.01, 0.08, 
    0.05, 0.07, 0.06, 0.01, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01, 0.06, 0.1, 0.07, 
    0.01, 0.05, 0.02, 0.08, 0.1, 0.03, 0.06, 0.02, 0.08, 0.09, 
    0.01, 0.06, 0.04, 0.07, 0.03, 0.03, 0.07, 0.01, 0.01, 0.06, 
    0.05, 0.04, 0.06, 0.04, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.09, 0.1, 0.07, 
    0.01, 0.08, 0.06, 0.01, 0.07, 0.06, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.09, 
    0.01, 0.07, 0.05, 0.07, 0.06, 0.1, 0.1, 0.08, 0.09)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -72L))
```

And here is my plot code:

```
A <- ggplot(res2, aes(Phenotype, heritability)) 
# uses a bar chart, geom_col represents hereditity values as the hights of the bars.  
A + geom_col(position = 'stack', fill = "#0000ff") +
  # Facets the data according to the Phenotypes in the X column of the data 
  facet_wrap(.~ X) +
  # Theme info: tilts the x-axis labels 90 degrees and pushes labels to be centered below the bars
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = .4), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  labs(title ="Heritability of Phenotype Permutations", subtitle = "P-values indicated")+
  # adds the pvalues above the bars, sets their position to be above or below the bar. 
  geom_text(aes(y = heritability + .06 * sign(heritability), label = pvalue), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 3.3)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: It already has labels. Do you mean labels on each grid?!

Comment: Yes, I would like there to be the labels on each grid if that is possible

Answer (score 2):

In `facet_wrap` you can specify `scales = 'free_x'`, which will allow each subplot to have its own x-axis including its own axis labels.
(Similar for `free_y` or `both`)

In your example using `facet_wrap(.~X, scales= 'free_x')` will produce the following plot:

[image]